# Start new Section before big picture from previous Section

Tags: sectioning, includegraphics, white-space

I would like to show a big diagram (full page,  coded as figure with \includegraphics) at the end of a Section (Section 1).
Unfortunately, the text of Section 1 does not end at the bottom of a page and I have a big white-space before the diagram.

Is there a way to start the text of of the next Section (Section 2) after the text of Section 1 and before the diagram to fill the white-space between Section 1 and the diagram?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what `\begin{figure}` ... `\end{figure}` is for.